# Compute the degree of field extension $\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$,$\sqrt[3]{2}$,$w$) where $w=-\frac{1}{2}$+$i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know that [$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$) : $\mathbb{Q}$]$=2$, [$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt[3]{2}$) : $\mathbb{Q}$]$=3$ and [$\mathbb{Q}$($w$) : $\mathbb{Q}$]$=2$ ; $w$=$-\frac{1}{2}$+$i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Does it imply [$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$$,$$\sqrt[3]{2}$$,$$w$)$:$$\mathbb{Q}$]$=2\cdot3\cdot2=12$ by simply multiply them together?

Or do we need to write [$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$$,$$\sqrt[3]{2}$$,$$w$):$\mathbb{Q}$]=[$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$$,$$\sqrt[3]{2}$$,$$w$):$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$$,$$\sqrt[3]{2}$)][$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$$,$$\sqrt[3]{2}$):$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt[3]{2}$)][$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt[3]{2}$):$\mathbb{Q}$]

where I have no idea on how to compute [$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$$,$$\sqrt[3]{2}$$,$$w$):$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{2}$$,$$\sqrt[3]{2}$)]. Could someone help me please?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056289/splitting-fields-of-x3-2x2-2). It is the splitting field of $(x^2-2)(x^3-2)$. Note that the $\zeta$ there is equal to $\omega$.

Comment: $2\cdot3\cdot2=12$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ are both real fields, with coprime degree over $\mathbb{Q}$. It follows (pretty standard textbook exercise) that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$ has degree 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Next, $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ clearly has degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$. But it is a nonreal field, so is not contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$. Since its degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 2, so must be its degree over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$. Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2},\omega):\mathbb{Q}] = 12$.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't just multiply them. For instance $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6})$ doesn't have degree $8$ over $\Bbb Q$ even though each of the fields $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{6})$ have degree $2$. One situation where you can simply multiply the degrees is when they are coprime, though (common textbook exercise).

You do have to use transitivity of degrees somehow for this problem. But you can simplify your field's description a bit to help with that. *Hint*: Rewrite your field with fewer, simpler terms:

$$ \Bbb Q\big(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\tfrac{1}{2}(-1+i\sqrt{3})\big) ~=~ \Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[6]{2}). $$

(Check containment in both directions to verify the equality. Do you see how I got this?)

Now, can you determine the degrees of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[6]{2})/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2})$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2})/\Bbb Q$?

Comment: I think this approach is slightly less obvious but still works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: May I further ask how to compute the degree of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[6]{2})/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2})$ ? I tried to make use of the fact that If the degree of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[6]{2})/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2})$ is equal to $1$,then $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3}):\Bbb Q]$ divides $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2}):\Bbb Q]$ to get a contradiction . But $2$ does divide $6$ and I am confused.

Comment: @mathnoob Either $x^2+3$ splits into linear factors over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2})$, which would imply $\sqrt{-3}$ is real, or else it is irreducible and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[6]{2})$ has degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2})$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you.